# Call the function in Python (not showing a graph)

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, graph

I want to use a function using the following codes.
It works well in the first place But when I try to call the function, it doesn't show anything but <Figure size 504x504 with 0 Axes> If you let me know why it will be much appreciated.

```
def plot_scatter(iris_pca):    
    plt.figure(figsize = (7,7))
    
sns.scatterplot(
    x="X1", y="X2",
    hue="target",
    data=iris_pca,
    legend="full",
    alpha=0.3)
```

A graph shows up.
but when I try to call the function above, it doesn't work properly.

```
plot_scatter(iris_pca)
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: The only code that belongs to that function is `plt.figure(figsize = (7,7))`, and this code doesn't attempt to plot anything.

Comment: You should indent your 'sns...' line  to be a part of python function. Please refer to Python documentation.

Comment: Your comments are really helpful to me. Thank you so much. I started learning Python a few weeks ago and am learning a lot. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a call to `plt.show()` to show your plot:

```py
def plot_scatter(iris_pca):    
    plt.figure(figsize = (7,7))
    
    sns.scatterplot(
        x="X1", y="X2",
        hue="target",
        data=iris_pca,
        legend="full",
        alpha=0.3)

    plt.show()
```

Comment: James, Thank you so much !!!! I just started learning Python and spent so many hours to try this simple issue. You save me :) Thanks.